# Having trouble uploading a file

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading a file.  First of all I have a class:

```
class upload

{
private $name;
private $document;
public function __construct($nme,$doc)
{
    $this->setName($nme);
    $this->setDocument($doc);
}
public function setName($nme)
{
    $this->name = $nme;
}
public function setDocument($doc)
{
    $this->document = $doc;
}
public function fileNotPdf()
{
    /* Was the file a PDF? */
    if ($this->document['type'] != "application/pdf") 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
public function fileNotUploaded()
{
    /* Make sure that the file was POSTed. */
    if (!(is_uploaded_file($this->document['tmp_name'])))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public function fileNotMoved($repositry)
{
        /* move uploaded file to final destination. */
        $result = move_uploaded_file($this->document['tmp_name'],
        "$repositry/$this->name.pdf");
        
        if($result)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
}
}
```

Now for my main page:

```
$docName = $_POST['name'];

$page = $_FILES['doc'];

if($_POST['submit'])

{
/* Set a few constants */
$filerepository = "np";
$uploadObj = new upload($docName, $page);
if($uploadObj->fileNotUploaded()) 
{
    promptUser("There was a problem uploading the file.","");
}
elseif($uploadObj->fileNotPdf())
{
    promptUser("File must be in pdf format.","");
}
elseif($uploadObj->fileNotMoved($filerepository))
{
    promptUser("File could not be uploaded to final destination.","");
}
else
{       
    promptUser("File has been successfully uploaded.","");
}
}
```

The errors that I get:

> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file(about.pdf)[function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
>
> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file()[function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'c:\xampp\tmp\php13.tmp' to 'about.pdf' in...
>
> File could not be uploaded to final destination.

Comment: Please fix the code formatting, you need to indent everything once more

Answer (score 3):

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) says:

> If *filename* is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and `move_uploaded_file()` will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

This is the only case when, according to the manual, a warning is issued, so I assume that this is what happens when you try to move the file.

> `move_uploaded_file()` is both `safe mode` and `open_basedir` aware. However, restrictions are placed only on the destination path as to allow the moving of uploaded files in which *filename* may conflict with such restrictions. `move_uploaded_file()` ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files uploaded through PHP to be moved.

My conclusion: There is no error in your code, your PHP configuration does not allow you to move the file to your target directory. You should research the limits imposed by `safe mode` and `open_basedir` to see why exactly the move operation fails.

Answer (score 2):

If I upload a file as "my_file", `"$repositry/$this->name.pdf"` will evaluate to `np/my_file.pdf`. That would put your target directory inside the tmp directory. The tmp directory should already exist and be writable, so make sure that the `np` directory exists inside the `tmp` directory. The `move_uploaded_file()` function will not create it automatically if it's missing. With the `np` directory missing, I was getting the same errors you are.

Also note that you shouldn't save uploaded files to a subdirectory of the tmp directory. I use XAMPP and when I run your code the uploaded file is moved to `tmp/np` and then deleted immediately.